# 'context:annotation-config' does not work in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am getting error for context:annotation-config/, Namespace & schema location seems fine, if i remove context:annotation-config tag, i don't red line under context.xsd

On hovering  tag, it says cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'.

[image]

UPDATE: I tried running the Application, It works fine, though I see red lines in xml file but App runs fine.

Comment: I guess you have conflicting version in your classpath. Try proving the version  in schema location like spring-context-4.0.xsd or whichever version you have

Comment: I tried that already, but same issue.

Comment: You need to rebuild after changing the version. Btw I am assuming this config will work on runtime but only showing error in your IDE. which one do you use?

Comment: Thanks, It still show error but I am able compile and execute it, I am using eclipse.